# sending mail with dynamically created pdf as attachment in c#

Tags: asp.net, email, pdf

I have to send emails with PDF attachments (dynamically created) in my web application (C#,ASP.NET).
How we can send mail with dynamically created pdf as attachment in c# (Asp.net)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send emails with their attachment(s) like this:

```
        List<string> attachments = //set a list of PDF paths here

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("SmtpHost", SmtpPort);
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("FromEmail", "FromName", Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("ToEmail", "ToName", Encoding.UTF8));

        //get a list of your file's paths from your program and use it here
        AddAttachments(mail.Attachments, attachments);

        mail.Subject = "Subject";
        mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = "Message";
        mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        //send an email
        smtpClient.Send(mail);

        //clean up
        mail.Dispose();


    void AddAttachments(AttachmentCollection attachment, List<string> attachments)
    {
        if (attachments != null)
        {
            foreach (string filePath in attachments)
                attachment.Add(new Attachment(filePath));
        }
    }
```